# How To Resize Certain ListView Columns Proportional To Remaining Size Of ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am attempting to re-size only certain columns of a ListView based on the remaining size after any static width column widths are calculated.  For example, I do not want columns, such as quantity, price, etc... to resize but, I would like columns that typically have wider data such as name, description to get wider.  Here is the method that I am attempting to use below but, it is not working.

BTW, I am calling this method when the ClientSizeChanged Event fires on the ListView.  Not sure if that is relevant or not.

```
    public static void ResizeListViewColumns(ListView lv, List<int> fixedColumnIndexes, List<int> nonFixedColumnIndexes)
    {
        int lvFixedWidth = 0;
        int lvNonFixedWidth = 0;
        if (fixedColumnIndexes.Count + nonFixedColumnIndexes.Count != lv.Columns.Count)
        {
            throw new Exception("Number of columns to resize does not equal number of columns in ListView");
        }
        else
        {
            // Calculate the fixed column width
            // Calculate the non-fixed column width
            // Calculate the new width of non-fixed columns by dividing the non-fixed column width by number of non-fixed columns
            foreach (var fixedColumn in fixedColumnIndexes)
            {
                lvFixedWidth += lv.Columns[fixedColumn].Width;
            }

            foreach (var nonFixedColumn in nonFixedColumnIndexes)
            {
                lvNonFixedWidth += lv.Columns[nonFixedColumn].Width;
            }

            int numNonFixedColumns = nonFixedColumnIndexes.Count;
            foreach (var newNonFixedColumn in nonFixedColumnIndexes)
            {
                lv.Columns[newNonFixedColumn].Width = lvNonFixedWidth / numNonFixedColumns;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should for you... Instead of keeping a list of fixed and unfixed indices, in my example I set the "Tag" property of each fixed column to the string "fixed".

```
int fixedWidth = 0;
        int countDynamic = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            ColumnHeader header = listView1.Columns[i];

            if (header.Tag != null && header.Tag.ToString() == "fixed")
                fixedWidth += header.Width;
            else
                countDynamic++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            ColumnHeader header = listView1.Columns[i];

            if (header.Tag == null)
                header.Width = ((listView1.Width - fixedWidth) / countDynamic);
        }
```

Comment: One quick question if you have a minute.  Is there an easy way to determine if the scroll bar is present so that an adjustment can be made to reduce the width of the last column by the width of the scroll bar?

Comment: My first guess would be try ListView.ClientSize as it should not include those portions including the scrollbars

Comment: Thanks!  You are awesome.  That accomplishes exactly what I was trying to do.